# I am working on Laravel with Bootstrap and Tailwind CSS. My tailwindcss is not been picked

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, tailwind-css

I have installed Laravel 5.8, updated my Tailwind version 0.1 to 1.1.4 and Bootstrap. My updated `tailwindcss` is not been read by the Laravel whenever I run the project. I have put a `"tw-"` to separate the Bootstrap from the `tailwindcss` like highlighted below. Still my `tailwindcss` is not working. Can anybody assist ...

```
options: {
    prefix: 'tw-',
    important: false,
    separator: ':',
},
```

Comment: Where is this config coming from? What do you mean by "running the project"?

Comment: You should give as more information about your config.

Comment: `is not been read` - do you mean 404s, the CSS file(s) is not found by the browser? Or that the styles aren't working on the page?

Comment: Did you run something like `npm run development -- --watch`?

Comment: @DavydeVries yes i did run the npm run development --watch / dev still no luck.

Comment: @Jerodev by running i meant compiling.

Comment: @Don'tPanic there is no 404s it is the tailwindcss classes which are not working on the page

Comment: @Emmanuel we cannot guess what is going wrong so show your webpack.mix.js package.jsonvand other config files in your opening post.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Bootstrap before and you haven't removed the bootstrap @import from your app.scss file - then tailwindcss will not be taken under account as it has its own @import directives. Make sure you remove the bootstrap first. You can't really use both. It's either / or.